# Grammar : Noun + Noun

Tags: grammar, prepositions

In this sentence

"I am absolutely determined — and I've spent a great deal of time and energy on this in the four months that I've been CIA director — to get to the bottom of the *question of what* and who caused this," Burns said.

Can I just say ~ to the bottom of the question what ~ ? Why should I use "of" between noun and noun. if so, what grammar should I study in order to learn "noun +  prepositon(of?) + noun
Thank you

Comment: I think your final question, *"what grammar should I study in order to learn "noun + prepositon(of?) + noun"* is too broad to be answered here.  [There are about 150 prepositions in English](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/prepositions-list.htm), and many of them have multiple meanings.

Comment: Yes, you can. The preposition is optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just saying "...to get to the bottom of the question what and who caused this", without the **of**, is unidiomatic even if it's understandable.  The only way I can think to make it sound right without *of* is to make it into a direct quotation:

> ...to get to the bottom of the question "what and who caused this?"

[**The question of X** is such a common stock phrase](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20question%20of%22&client=firefox-b-1-d&sxsrf=ALeKk031nz4cX5ioVyfX9K8D_HG5ydRUkA:1626998513657&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiz_NLj8ffxAhXFFlkFHWKZATgQ_AUoAXoECAEQCw&biw=1449&bih=778) that any change to it is going to look very strange.

**Of** in this sentence means one of its normal meanings:

> [5a : relating to : about](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/of)

It's not just any question, it's the question *relating to this particular thing*.